# how to get Message delivery receipt for a message sent to PUBSUB node using smack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, openfire, smack

I am developing android chat app using smack library Using Openfire/ Ejabberd XMPP server. I am working on PUBSUB and able to create PUBSUB node, send a message to the node, receive a message, etc.

Now, I want to get message delivery receipt of the message sent.
I searched for it and what I am getting is:

```
Chat chat;
if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(threadId)) {
chat = getChatManager().createChat(to);
Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: no thread id so created Chat with id: " + chat.getThreadID());
} else {
chat = getChatManager().getThreadChat(threadId);
Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage: thread id was used to continue this chat");
}

Message message = new Message(to);
message.addBody("EN", messageText);
String deliveryReceiptId = DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(message);
chat.sendMessage(message);
```

and for receiving the delivery receipts:

```
DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection).addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiptReceived(String fromJid, String toJid, String deliveryReceiptId, Stanza stanza) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceiptReceived: from: " + fromJid + " to: " + toJid + " deliveryReceiptId: " + deliveryReceiptId + " stanza: " + stanza);
    }
});
```

But this is code for sending the message using org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message object which is for sending a message in MUC chat. The way by which message is sent over PUBSUB node is different i.e. payload object as given in [this](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/documentation/extensions/pubsub.md) link:

```
// Create a pubsub manager using an existing XMPPConnection
PubSubManager mgr = PubSubManager.getInstanceFor(con);

// Get the node
LeafNode node = mgr.getNode("testNode");

// Publish an Item with payload
node.send(new PayloadItem("test" + System.currentTimeMillis(),
new SimplePayload("book", "pubsub:test:book", "Two Towers")));
```

So the question is, how to get message delivery receipts for a message sent to PUBSUB node by using the above code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can anyone guide me on this? How to get delivery receipt for a message sent to muc or pubsub node?